# How to add pre-installed ASP.NET components without downloading it in Visual Studio installer

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I got all the framework files of .net, ASP.NET from my friend. After installing Visual Studio 2017 Community, I don't want to download the templates or packages from  VS installer as I have already on my PC. Please tell how can I add/import components of ASP.NET etc? And on new project option, it shows blank solution and no way to import from there. Is there a way I can add without downloading huge files?

Comment: Please read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

Comment: I do not think this is possible.
But maybe this link can help you: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/issues/741